# Stripe to Stripe Transfer

Tags: stripe-connect

I want to use Stripe Connect in my iOS project. My requirement is to transfer an amount from my platform account to a connected account. This is possible with 'Special case transfers' but it has some limitations. Due to this, I'm planning to accept payment on my one connected account and will then transfer it on to another. It is possible to transfer an amount from one connected account to another?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the amount you have to transfer. If you only need to wire less than 10% of your overall net volume, you can use special cases transfer. I am actually using it on my platform like this :

```
Stripe::Transfer.create(
  amount: params[:amount].to_i,
  currency: 'eur',
  destination: params[:stripe_id]
)
```

Anyway, you cannot transfer funds from a connected account to another. I already faced this situation, and I contacted Stripe support who confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stripe connect plateform provide such things
at first deducted amount submitted to stripe admin account than admin account to respective bank account.

doc : https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers
stripe.transfers.create(
  {
    amount: 400,
    currency: 'gbp',
    destination: account_id,
    transfer_group: 'ORDER_95'
  },
  function(err, transfer) {
  }
);
```